# Not getting data in post form

Tags: node.js, express

i've been trying to get the data in a form with the POST method, but i don't get any, i've been reading a book to learn about expressjs.. this is my form:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usernameInput" class="col-md-2">Username</label>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usernameInput" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="passwordInput" class="col-md-2">Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordInput" name="password" placeholder="Enter password">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log in</button>
</form>
```

and this is my node code.

```
/*
Chat application for @node.js
express version.
*/

//Load modules.
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    socket = require('socket.io'),
    swig = require('swig'),
    fs = require('fs');

//Load config.
console.log('Loading configuration.');
var config = fs.readFileSync('config.json');
var config = JSON.parse(config);
var port = config.port;
var views = config.views;
console.log('Configuration loaded.');

//Initiate express module in app.
var app = express();


//Global vars
var Title = "Node.js Chat";
var result = '';


app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);

//Set view engine.
app.set('view engine', 'html');

//Set the directory for views.
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

swig.setDefaults(
{
    cache: false
});

app.get('/', function(request, response)
{
    console.log('GET OK');
    response.render('index',
    {
        'Title': Title,
        'result': result,
    });
});

app.post('/', function(request, response)
{
    console.log('POST OK');
    console.log(request.body);

    response.render('index',
    {
        'Title': Title,
        'result': 'Post detected.',
    });
});

//logger.
app.use(function(request, response, next)
{
    console.log('%s %s', request.method, request.url);

    var file = request.url.slice(1 + request.url.indexOf('/'));

    app.get(request.url, function(request, response)
    {
        response.render(file,
        {
            //Var to be named in the render : value;
            'Title': Title,
            'result': result,
        });
    });

    next();
});


//Set directory for static files (css, js, img)
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//Run the app.
http.createServer(app).listen(port, function()
{
    console.log('Server listening to ' + port);
});
```

i get "undefined" in request.body, which i dont know why i get this error, i've tried with other methods like request.param, or request.query, but they get nothing, i've made sure the post is detected and its why it sends the message that's being detected, but i want to get the data in the form..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the now-separate [body-parser middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser). Run `npm install body-parser` or add `body-parser` to your package.json and `npm install` it.

Add `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');` to your module-loading, then after instantiating your `app`, add the middleware with `app.use(bodyParser());`. That will populate `req.body` for the form.

Comment: there's not a way that express could do it without installing another module?

Comment: Not in that form (`req.body`). Express pulled these modules out of its own module in part so they could be updated/included/excluded more easily.

Comment: alright, i'll keep in mind i have to install a new module for post.. thank you

Comment: i tested it with the checkbox, but checkbox is not detected, i tried giving it a name, but it doesnt work

Comment: Using the body-parser middleware and a copy/paste of your html except for adding `name="checkbox"` to the checkbox input let me see `req.body.checkbox` on the server after posting. If the box is checked, the value is 'on'. If it's unchecked, there is no property sent.

Answer (score 0):

add in app.js:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

As the comment indicated, it depends on the express version.

It works with 3.x as stated above.

For 4.0, you must manually include these frameworks that were previously included. See the note from vision media (overview tab):

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x

These are NOT included to allow independent updates

Comment: This has been [deprecated](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x#overview). Express no longer includes the `bodyParser` middleware.

Comment: In 4.0 yes, I don't know what OP is using since it wasn't working I assumed 3.x. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: It should also be noted that `body-parser` does not include multipart form handling. For that you will need a separate module that can handle those kinds of requests.